# How to add double quotes in each field and print new row on next line - PHP CSV

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I have a file data whom I creating CSV file manually.

Then I parse that file and picked necessary data and create new CSV file from it.

Till that step things are good and working but the problem is when I open that new file in text file, it misses double quotes around each fields and there is no new line at the ending of each row.

Here is the data of CSV file:

```
TransactionNumber   CustomerName    ReferenceNumber PurchaseOrderNumber ShipCarrier ShipService ShipBilling ShipAccount EarliestShipDate    CancelDate  Notes   ShipToName  ShipToCompany   ShipToAddress1  ShipToAddress2  ShipToCity  ShipToState ShipToZip   ShipToCountry   ShipToPhone ShipToFax   ShipToEmail ShipToCustomerName  ShipToDeptNumber    ShipToVendorID  TotalCartons    TotalPallets    TotalWeight TotalVolume BOLNum  TrackingNum TrailerNum  SealNum ShipDate    ItemNumber  ItemQuantityOrdered ItemQuantityShipped ItemLength  ItemWidth   ItemHeight  ItemWeight  FreightPP   WarehouseID LotNumber   SerialNumber    ExpirationDate  Supplier    Cost    FulfillInvShippingAndHandling   FulfillInvTax   FulfillInvDiscountCode  FulfillInvDiscountAmount    FulfillInvGiftMessage   SoldToName  SoldToCompany   SoldToAddress1  SoldToAddress2  SoldToCity  SoldToState SoldToZip   SoldToCountry   SoldToPhone SoldToFax   SoldToEmail SoldToCustomerID    SoldToDeptNumber    FulfillInvSalePrice FulfillInvDiscountPct   FulfillInvDiscountAmt
242328  PARADIGM TRENDS 123810  40-402849   CUSTOMER PICK UP    LTL FreightCollect                  HG BUYING- JEFFERSON DC 884 HG BUYING- JEFFERSON DC 884 125 LOGISTICS CENTER PKWY       JEFFERSON   AL  30549   US                          30  0   30  0.0174      22              DOV3S   64  64  4   1   1   4   22  1                       0   0       0                                                           0   0   0
222223      123812  40-402850                                                                                       12      3                           DOV3M   64  64  4   1   1   4   442                                                                                                 0   0   0
242423      1238120 40-402851                                                                                       33      67          3               BY3S    176 176 11  1   1   11  2                                                                                                   0   0   0
7868        1233810 40-402852                                                                                       44      55          33              BY3M    176 176 11  1   1   11  45                                                                                                  0   0   0
989879      1234810 40-402853                                                                                       53      442         7                                           6                                                                                                           
        1253810 40-402854                                                                                       66                  88                                                                                                                                                      
898     1263810 40-402855                                                                                       88      66                                                      6                                                                                                           
888     1273810 40-402856                                                                                       32      88                                                      33                                                                                                          
333     1235810 40-402857                                                                                       8       8           9                                           5                                                                                                           
55      1233810 40-402858                                                                                       8       33                                                      7                                                                                                           
99      3332223 40-402859                                                                                       8       7           96                                          5                                                                                                           
996     356666  40-402860                                                                                       8       65          44
```

Here the output of new file in text file:

```
123810,30,"CUSTOMER PICK UP",22,22,30123812,12,,,442,31238120,33,,3,2,67 1233810,44,,33,45,551234810,53,,7,6,4421263810,88,,,6,661273810,32,,,33,88
1235810,8,,9,5,81233810,8,,,7,333332223,8,,96,5,7356666,8,,44,,65
```

The desired output is:

```
"123810","30","CUSTOMER PICK UP","22","22","30"
"123812","12","","","442","3"
...
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);

$realPath = realpath( dirname(__FILE__) );
$path     = glob($realPath.'/3pltracking/*.csv');
$UpdPath  = $realPath . '/3pltracking/';
$files    = scandir($UpdPath);
$date     = date('m-d-Y_his');
$result   = array();
$csvData  = array();



if (file_exists($path[0])) 
{
    if (($handle = fopen($path[0], "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $i=0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $i++;
                if($i==1) continue;
                if($data[2] != ""){
                        $csvData[] = $data[2].','.$data[25].','.$data[4].','.$data[30].','.$data[41].','.$data[27];
                    }
            }

        fclose($handle);
        $fp      = fopen($realPath.'/3pltracking/TrackingFiles/Tracking_File_'.$date.'.csv', 'w');
        foreach ($csvData as $line) {
            fputcsv($fp, explode(",", $line));
        }
        fclose($fp);
        echo "Your CSV File Has Been Created In Folder Name => 'TrackingFiles' On Your FTP";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please Upload Your CSV File First";
        }

        copy($UpdPath.$files[2], $realPath.'/3pltracking/UsedFiles/'.date('Y-m-d').'_'.rand(111, 999).'-'.$files[2]);
        //unlink($path[0]);
?>
```

Comment: Only those fields which need to be quoted are quoted. Also newline character is probably \n and your text editor expects \r\n. So the csv you produce is valid as it is most likely. Why would you want quotes around *every* field?

Comment: @SergeyEremin It is the requirement of client as they need this format of file plus they need to import that file in quick books.

Comment: That means you will have stop using fputcsv() and build csv lines manually. If you can, try telling your client that this requirement is strange from the technical point of view.

Comment: @SergeyEremin Technically you are right in saying that but there is common theory in world that client is always right and when it comes to non technical client things become more worst. :) Btw any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better when you build your csvData array to build a matrix and then you do not need to bother with the explode.

```php
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $i++;
    if($i==1) continue;
    if($data[2] != "") {
        $csvData[] = [$data[2], $data[25], $data[4], $data[30], $data[41], $data[27]];
    }
}

fclose($handle);
$fp = fopen($realPath.'/3pltracking/TrackingFiles/Tracking_File_'.$date.'.csv', 'w');
foreach ($csvData as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

Then as @SergeyEremin mentioned, when you use fputcsv only fields that need to be enclosed will be, ie. fields with spaces or special chars etc.

If you absolutely need every field to be enclosed with quotes then you should probably not use `fputcsv` but rather build the line exactly how you want it and just use `fputs`.

```php
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $i++;
    if($i==1) continue;
    if($data[2] != "") {
        $csvData[] = '"' . $data[2] . '","' . $data[25] . '","' . $data[4] . '","' . $data[30] . '","' .  $data[41] . '","' . $data[27] . '"' . "\r\n";
    }
}

fclose($handle);
$fp = fopen($realPath.'/3pltracking/TrackingFiles/Tracking_File_'.$date.'.csv', 'w');
foreach ($csvData as $row) {
    fputs($fp, $row);
}
```

Comment: Yes, fputs did the job and it is solved as well :) You the man. :)

Comment: What is difference between fputs and fputcsv?

Comment: fputs just writes a line to the file pointer, while fputcsv formats the array as a CSV line and writes to the file pointer. With Sergey's comment still being important. Chances are that your clients requirement for absolutely every field to be enclosed is technically not needed. But then as you said - the client is always right, and it might not be worth it for a technical battle.

Answer (score 1):

```
function alternative_fputcsv($handle, $fields, $delimiter = ",", $enclosure = '"', $newline = "\r\n") {
    $string = $enclosure . implode($enclosure . $delimiter . $enclosure, $fields) . $enclosure . $newline;
    return fwrite($handle, $string);
}
```

Call this function instead fputcsv. Should work exaclty the same, but give you your client's expected behaviour.

Unrelated advice: this `$data[2].','.$data[25].','.$data[4].','.$data[30].','.$data[41].','.$data[27]` will give you invalid csv if there is a comma in any of the fields. Why not put these fields into an array instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);

$realPath = realpath( dirname(__FILE__) );
$path     = glob($realPath.'/3pltracking/*.csv');
$UpdPath  = $realPath . '/3pltracking/';
$files    = scandir($UpdPath);
$date     = date('m-d-Y_his');
$result   = array();
$csvData  = array();



if (file_exists($path[0])) 
{
    if (($handle = fopen($path[0], "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $i=0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $i++;
                if($i==1) continue;
                if($data[2] != ""){
                        //Changed the line below
                        $csvData[] = '"'.$data[2].'","'.$data[25].'","'.$data[4].'","'.$data[30].'","'.$data[41].'","'.$data[27].'"'."\r\n";
                    }
            }

        fclose($handle);
        $fp      = fopen($realPath.'/3pltracking/TrackingFiles/Tracking_File_'.$date.'.csv', 'w');
        foreach ($csvData as $line) {
            fputcsv($fp, explode(",", $line));
        }
        fclose($fp);
        echo "Your CSV File Has Been Created In Folder Name => 'TrackingFiles' On Your FTP";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please Upload Your CSV File First";
        }

        copy($UpdPath.$files[2], $realPath.'/3pltracking/UsedFiles/'.date('Y-m-d').'_'.rand(111, 999).'-'.$files[2]);
        //unlink($path[0]);
?>
```

Comment: Output: `"""123810""","""30""","""CUSTOMER PICK UP""","""22""","""22""","""30"""
"""123812""","""12""","""""","""""","""442""","""3"""
"""1238120""","""33""","""""","""3""","""2""","""67"""
"""1233810""","""44""","""""","""33""","""45""","""55"""
"""1234810""","""53""","""""","""7""","""6""","""442"""
` and its not on new line as well. 
It should be on new line as well plus just `""` in each field

Comment: Yes its good for new line. checked your editted answer but `"""123810""","""30"""` when it should `"123810","30"`